# Uncaught (in promise) Error: GraphQL error: Not Authorised

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo

When I try to update user's details on my react app, this error pops up.

My app uses Firebase services and GraphQL for data fetching. It is written in ReactJS.

Answer (score 0):

The graphql endpoint you are querying requires some form of authentication. This is most likely an access token that you have to insert as a header into the request by configuring the apollo client or whatever you are using.

You will first have to obtain that token from somewhere.

It should be something similar to that:

```
import ApolloClient, { InMemoryCache } from "apollo-boost";

const token = await auth.currentUser.getIdToken(true);

const client = new ApolloClient({
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  headers: { token: token },
  uri: // <insert endpoint uri>
});
```